# Effectiveness of 1000 BWC in practice

Tags: 1000-blank-white-cards

To anyone that has played [1000bwc](http://1000bwc.org/), or seen it played:

- Does it really work in practice?
- Does it only work for fun, or can you get a semi-serious competative game out of it?
- Does anyone actually play this game or is it a random novelty?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. **It really works in practice**. I've been part of an annual game of 1KBWC for many years, and it's still fun.
2. **It only works for fun**. Any competitive elements present are pastiches of elements of other games.
3. **I actually play this game.** That does not prevent it from being a random novelty, but it answers the first part of the question handily.

Comment: It being a random novelty, you probably don't want to play it too often or it'll lose its magic a bit. We played a huge game once a couple years ago, and still talk about it now and then; it was awesome! If we played it more often I suspect it'd be less awesome.

Comment: Yup. Don't play it for any actual gameplay. Play it because it's hilarious, go with whatever themes and silliness evolve, and you'll talk about it later.

Comment: Right, now I just need to get a game together! Thanks to @Jadasc for your answer, and to others for comments. :)

Comment: I've played it a few times. So much fun. Enjoying pulling out the old cards and remembering the craziness.

Comment: A lot of the fun you get from a game of 1000BWC comes from the people you choose to play it with.  There are lots of people I'd never play it with, just 'cause they're not going to "get" it.  That said, it's a fun, game-like surrealist exercise.